# unlock a mac with a program

Tags: mac, user-accounts, osx-mavericks

Does anyone know of a way to make a program or simple script that could be run that would have the capability of unlocking my mac and/or security prompts in osx mavericks.

I understand that a user password would undoubtably need to be included somewhere in the program or script to make this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware this isnt possible as the program wont be able to be run from the login screen. Could you please give us an example of how this script will be used?

Comment: well in the end im going to set it so it would be run automatically when triggered by a event.  i already have that working, but not a program or script to be run that would unlock it.                      ...Sorry if im being confusing...